# Logic not evaluating correct - Angular11

Tags: angular, typescript, logic, angular11

I got method to setRemark to display message passed or failed based on grade

Elementary grade = 75 is passed
College grade = 3 is passed

```
   private getFinalGrade(studentId: number, gradingSections: IGradingSection[], transmutation: ITransmutation) {
        let finalGrade: number = 0;
        let grades: number[] = [];
        let gradingSectionNumber = gradingSections.length;
        for (let gradingSection of gradingSections) {
            let weightedPercentageGrade = (new StudentGradeComputerService(studentId))
                .setAssessment(gradingSection.assessments)
                .setTransmutation(transmutation)
                .generate()
                .getTotalWeightedScore();
            grades.push(weightedPercentageGrade);
            finalGrade += weightedPercentageGrade;
        }
        return {grades, finalGrade: finalGrade / gradingSectionNumber};
    }
    
    private setRemark(grades: number, removalGrade: number) {
        if(removalGrade) {
            grades = removalGrade;
        }
        let passingGrade = (grades < 6) ? 3 : 75;
        let condition = (passingGrade == 3) ? (grades <= 3) : (grades >= passingGrade);
        console.log(condition)
        return (condition && grades != 0) ? "Passed" : "Failed";
    }
```

**UPDATED**
here's where i call setRemark

```
private getStudentScheduleBySession(studentRecord): void {
        let studentReportData: object[] = [];
        let maxGradingSections: number = 1;
        studentRecord.forEach((subject) => {
            let newData = subject;
            let grades = this.getFinalGrade(subject.student_id, subject.schedule.class_record.sections, subject.schedule.class_record.transmutation);
            newData["finalGrade"] = grades.finalGrade;
            newData["grades"] = grades.grades;
            newData["remark"] = this.setRemark(newData["final_grade"], newData["removal_grade"]);
            studentReportData.push(newData);

            maxGradingSections = (grades.grades.length > maxGradingSections) ? grades.grades.length : maxGradingSections;
        })
        this.maxGradingSections = maxGradingSections;
        this.studentReportData = studentReportData;
    }
```

The problem is even the grade is 70 its still showing passed. I don't know what's the problem with my logic.

[image]

Comment: Look fine if I use `setRemark(70, 0)`. Are you pass any value for the second parameter? How did you call the `setRemark` method?

Comment: thanks fortaking time to respond. I'll update my post bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code snippet for getStudentScheduleBySession method, u stored the value of new grade in to newData["finalGrade"]. But in setRemark method passing variable name is newData["final_grade"]. I think it should be newData["finalGrade"].

Comment: thanks for the answer bro. Tried your solution it still gives me passed even though my grade is 70

Comment: As per the code snippet for getStudentScheduleBySession method, u stored the value of new grade in to newData["finalGrade"]. But in setRemark method passing variable name is newData["final_grade"].  I think it should be newData["finalGrade"].

Comment: wow it really is the solution. Didn't notice that typo. You can post your solution bro so i can vote for it.

Comment: update the post with the solution...